# Why is my AJAX not calling the controller method in MVC?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call a method in my controller and pass some data to it that I retrieve from my form (input), I want to print the resulting view that is called by the controller to #resultDiv as shown below but it seems to me that the controller method that I'm calling in ajax isn't being reached & I don't know where the problem is, please help

Here is my js (ajax) file :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#rechercheInput').submit(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var villeDepart = $("#depart").val();
       var villeArrivee = $("#arrivee").val();
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  'ajaxDispatcher.php?action=ajaxRechercherVoyage',
            data: {depart: villeDepart, arrivee: villeArrivee},
            dateType: 'html',
            success: function (code_html, statut) {
              console.log(code_html);
              $("#resultDiv").html(code_html);
            }
       })
       return false;
     }
      )
   });
```

Here is the Controller method that should be called :

```
public static function ajaxRechercherVoyage($request,$context){
    
        $trajet = trajetTable::getTrajet($request['depart'], $request['arrivee']);
        $context->voyages = voyageTable::getVoyagesByTrajet($trajet->id);
        echo 'success of ajax function';
        return context::SUCCESS;
    
    echo 'error of ajax function';
    return context::ERROR;
}
```

and here is the View from where I submit the form and call Ajax :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <form method="POST" action="" id="searchForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="searchInput" value="<?php echo $action ?>">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label for="depart">Ville de depart</label>
                </div>
                <select name="depart" id="depart" >
                    <?php foreach($context->villes as $ville) { ?>
                    <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['depart']) && $_REQUEST['depart'] == $ville){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $ville ?>" selected><?php echo $ville ?></option>
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $ville ?>"><?php echo $ville ?></option>
                    <?php } } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div>
            <div>
                <span for="arrivee">Ville d arrivee</>
            </div>
            <select name="arrivee" id="arrivee">
                <?php foreach($context->villes as $ville) { ?>
                <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['arrivee']) && $_REQUEST['arrivee'] == $ville){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $ville ?>" selected><?php echo $ville ?></option>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $ville ?>"><?php echo $ville ?></option>
                <?php } } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    </br> </br>
    <div class="col"> <button type="submit" id="searchButton">
            Rechercher</button> </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="resultDiv">
    I want the result to show here.
</div>
```

Note : The ajax file is reached properly because it worked with a simpler ajax code without data parameters... and sorry about some of the names being in French lol

Comment: Please check the console for any errors.

Comment: @adiga I forgot to mention, no errors in the console. The problem is the method is not even called since I can't see its echo

Comment: What is `$request` and how is it populated? Have you checked your web servers error log to see if PHP throws any errors when it doesn't work? Have you checked the "network tab" in the browsers development tools to see if the request is made, what it sends and what the response is when you make your ajax request?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have checked the network tab and the method that I want to call isn't called. I don't know how to access the web server error log since I'm working with the university's server

Comment: If no request is made to the PHP code, then the issue isn't with PHP but rather with the JavaScript code. Btw, in your ajax code, you have `dateType: 'html',`, it shouild be `dataType` (shouldn't fix your main issue though.)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ah okay, also when I click on the submit button of the form the page refreshes, when it's not supposed to refresh when using ajax

Comment: Your form has the id `searchForm` but you add the submit event handler on `rechercheInput`. If you want to catch the form, you need to use `$('#searchForm').submit(....)` instead. Currently, it's listening for a submit event on some other element (can't even find it in your code) so the ajax code will never be executed and isn't related to the form at all.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you so much, I changed it and it fixed my problem I love you bro!!!